# wrapper not defined ERROR - LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class

I am complete novice to JS and LWC. I am trying to pass multiple params to ma APEX class. And still getting "[wrapper is not defined]" In the example, i am passing just one string. The goal is to eventualy have searchable LWC datatable with multiple params. I can do it with one param. The issue is with multiple once - hence trying to learn wrapper approach. Thank you for the input.

js:

```
export default class PTHDatatable extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    PTSearchValue;
    dateFrom;
    displayResults;
    columns = columns;
    handlePTSearch(event){
        this.PTSearchValue=event.target.value;
        this.handleSearch();
    }
 
    handleSearch(){
        let parameterObject = {
            PTSearch: this.PTSearchValue,
        };
        getData({wrapper: parameterObject})
            .then((result)=>{
            this.displayResults=result;})
        
    }
```

Wrapper class

```
 public with sharing class CustomWrapper {
            
            @AuraEnabled
            public String PTsearch { get; set; }
    }
```

And html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Project task search">
        <lightning-button onclick={handleclick} value="Create AR" label="Create AR"></lightning-button>
        <lightning-input type="text" placeholder="Enter search value" onchange={handlePTSearch} class="slds-m-arpund_medium"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input type="date" value="4.11.2022" placeholder="Enter search value" onchange={handledateFrom} class="slds-m-arpund_medium"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={displayResults}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

And APEX class

```
    public PTHDatatable() {
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Project_Task_Hours__c> getData(CustomWrapper wrapper){
        
        try {
            String PTName = '%' + wrapper.PTsearch + '%';
        List<Project_Task_Hours__c> data = new List<Project_Task_Hours__c>([SELECT Id,Name,Project_Task__c,Date__c,Project_Task_t__c 
                                                                            FROM Project_Task_Hours__c 
                                                                            WHERE Project_Task__r.Name 
                                                                            LIKE :PTName
                                                                            LIMIT 50]);
            return data;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is typo,see the difference between **PTSearch and PTsearch**, you are passing wrapper as:-

```
let parameterObject = {
            PTSearch: this.PTSearchValue,
        };
```

where as your method expect it as:-

```
let parameterObject = {
            PTsearch: this.PTSearchValue,
        };
```